# Linux GTHD SCSI driver date format?

Tags: linux, raid, intel

I'm having a bit of a problem with my Intel SATA Raid controller on a remote Linux machine. I've recovered the error descriptions from /proc/scsi/gdth/0 and everything makes perfect sense except for the date format. A log excerpt is included below:

Controller Events:
 date- 1678:59:04       Adapter 0: SATA-A, ID 0: A media error was reported by the disk drive.

Anyone have any idea how to decipher when this has actually happened?

Answer (score 1):

I would go look for the system messages in /var/log/messages instead. The timestamp there should be usable